# How to pass url as configuration parameter in Behave Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, python-behave

I am starting using behave and selenium to write automative tests. I want to create parameter called url as an configuration parameter and:
- be able to set it's default value 
- be able to pass it as an argument from command line

I know I should be able to use userdata to achieve this, but I can't figure out how exactly. Can anybody help? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass directly any variable your behave execution needs via CLI, in my project we use it on Jenkins CI (Shell step) like so:

```
python -m behave -D platform=desktop -D os=linux -D test.environment=$environment -D browser=remote.chrome -D jenkins.job=$JOB_NAME $TAGS -t=~ignore --no-skipped --no-capture --junit --junit-directory junit_reports
```

In our `behave.ini`:

```
[behave.userdata]
browser=chrome
platform=desktop   ;this should be configurable via behave @tags
os=windows
test.environment=staging
```

Then in Python code just access the data:

```
if context.config.userdata['browser'].lower() == ApplicationDriversEnum.SELENIUM_CHROME:
    driver = __create_chrome_driver(context)
```

Comment: Happy to hear @Ewa. StackOverflow has clear policy for helpful answers, just accept mine if you find it useful, so others may find it more easily in future.